# Why is the "lambda" required in the code below

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am tying to implement a function that computes a mean squared error of two input vectors.

```
# function has to take 2 vectors and return a single number
# <define_inputs_and_transformations()>
vector1 = tf.placeholder('float32',shape=(None,))
vector2 = tf.placeholder('float32',shape=(None,))
# mse =<define_transformation()>
mse = tf.reduce_mean(vector1 - vector2)**2
#compute_mse = lambda vector1, vector2: <how to run graph?>
```

How should I run the graph given the structure above. Why is "lambda" needed to run the graph? 
usually, I would do the following:

```
mse.eval({vector1:dummy1,vector2:dummy2})
```

Comment: I don't follow your question? Do you want to know why the lambda is required or how to run the graph? Why do you think you can't do what you would "usually" do?

Comment: @cs95 Yes, I would like to know why lambda is required.
I am also trying to run the graph in the following form: 
`#compute_mse = lambda vector1, vector2: <how to run graph?>`

Comment: @cs95 any ideas?